# MongoDB: Tree Node Structure with Object-Maps instead of Collections

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, tree, data-modeling, nosql

Using MongoDB for storage, if I wanted to represent a tree structure of nodes, where child nodes under a single parent always have unique node-names, I believe the standard approach would be to use collections and to manage the node name uniqueness on the app level:

**Approach 1: Collection Based Approach for Tree Data**

```
{ "node_name": "home", "title": "Home", "children": [
    { "node_name": "products", "title": "Products", "children": [
        { "node_name": "electronics", "title": "Electronics", "children": [ ] },
        { "node_name": "toys", "title": "Toys", "children": [ ] } ] },
    { "node_name": "services", "title": "Services", "children": [
        { "node_name": "repair", "title": "Repair", "children": [ ] },
        { "node_name": "training", "title": "Training"", "children": [ ] } ] } ] }
```

I have however thought of the following alternate approach, where node-names become "Object Map" field names, and we do without collections altogether:

**Approach 2: Object-Map Based Approach (without Collections)**

```
// NOTE: We don't have the equivalent of "none_name":"home" at the root, but that's not an issue in this case
{ "title": "Home", "children": {
    "products": { "title": "Products", children": {
        "electronics": { "title": "Electronics", "children": { } },
        "toys": { "title": "Toys", "children": { } } } },
    "services": { "title": "Services", children": {
        "repair": { "title": "Repair", "children": { } },
        "training": { "title": "Training", "children": { } } } } } }
```

## The question is:

Strictly from a MongoDB perspective (considering querying, performance, data maintainability and data-size and server scaling), are there any major issues with Approach #2 (over #1)?

**EDIT:** After getting to know MongoDB a bit better (and thanks to Neil's comments below), I realized that both options of this question are generally the wrong way to go, because they assume that it makes sense to store multiple nodes in a single MongoDB document. Ultimately, each "node" should be a separate document and (as  Neil Lunn stated in the comments) there are various ways to implement a hierarchy tree, as seen here: [Model Tree Structures in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/)

Comment: Neither are really great, and for anything of reasonable size you should probably flatten it. This is a common data modelling task and not just for MongoDB, so the good approaches have already been discussed at length. The manual itself has whole section on [Modelling Tree Structures](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) which is likely more comprehensive than any response that could be offered here.

Comment: In general, I agree, but I'm posting here because AFAIK no MongoDB documentation touches the approach of using field-based maps to represent conceptually separate entities without collections (or references) in-between.

Comment: I mostly refer you there because unless you absolutely never intend to modify your "tree structure" or traverse it in any way then "those suggestions" are a lot better than storing everything in a single document in a collection. There are two ways to consider an idea where you find nothing like it. 1. It's either brand new and brilliant 2. People have considered it before and it is full of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think this use-case is not good for Mongo DB, because:

- there's(MongoDB 2.6) no compress algorithm (your documents will be too large)
- Mongo DB use database-level locks (when you want one large document, all DB operations will be blocked)
- it will be hard to index

I think better solution will be some relational DB for this use-case.